# Using PayPal developer with Angular, but cannot get the item's name, quantity, or price. I only get the total price

Tags: html, angular, typescript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I will need help from someone who is experienced with PayPal Developer. When I make a payment through Sandbox, I only get a receipt of the total price, and not the price of each item. I need to be notified what items my customers will be purchasing.

cart.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CardsModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
//import { Server } from 'http';
import { CartService } from 'src/app/service/service.service';
import { CheckoutService } from 'src/app/service/checkout.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IPayPalConfig, ICreateOrderRequest } from 'ngx-paypal';
import {render} from 'creditcardpayments/creditCardPayments';
import emailjs, { EmailJSResponseStatus, init } from '@emailjs/browser';
import { isNgTemplate } from '@angular/compiler';
init("user ...");

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.scss']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

  public products : any = [];
  public grandTotal !: number;
  paymentHandler: any = null;
  
  constructor(private cartService : CartService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cartService.getProducts()
    .subscribe(res=>{
      this.products = res;
      this.grandTotal = this.cartService.getTotalPrice();
    })
  }

  totalItemPayment(quantity: number, price: number){
    return quantity * price;
  }

  removeItem(item: any){
    this.cartService.removeCartItem(item);
  }

  emptycart(){
    this.cartService.removeAllCart();
  }

  checkout(){
    const myValue: any = this.grandTotal;
    console.log("total price (value) = " + myValue);
    let text = JSON.stringify(this.cartService.cartItemList);
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(text);
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++)
    {

      // tracks the item name, quantity, price in console.log
      const description = "quantity: " + jsonObj[i]['quantity'] + "\ntitle: " + jsonObj[i]['title'] + "\n\n";
      console.log("item name = " + description);
    }

    // I would like to find a way to put the item name, quanity, and price in render.
    render(
      {
        id: "#myPaypalButtons",
        currency: "USD",
        value: myValue,
        onApprove: (details) => {
          alert("Payment Successful!");
          this.emptycart();
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

cart.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
        <ng-container *ngIf="products.length !=0">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card-table">
                    <div class="cart-product">
                        <table class="table table-responsive">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Sr.No</th>
                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                    <th>Product Image</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let item of products; let i = index">
                                    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                                    <td><img style="width: 40px;" src="{{item.image}}" alt=""></td>
                                    <td style="width: 25%;">{{item.description}}</td>
                                    <th style="width: 12%;">{{item.price}}</th>
                                    <td style="width: 12%;">{{item.quantity}}</td>
                                    <td style="width: 12%;">{{item.price*item.quantity}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button (click)="removeItem(item)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <p></p>
                            <br>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4"></td>
                                    <td class="a"><button (click)="emptycart()" class="btn btn-danger">Empty Cart</button></td>
                                    <td class="b"><button routerLink="/products" class="btn btn-primary">Shop More</button></td>
                                    <!--<td><button (click)="checkout()">Checkout</button></td>-->
                                    <td class="c"><button (click)="checkout()" class="btn btn-success"> Submit </button></td>
                                    <div id="error-message"></div>
                                    <td class="d"><strong>Total Price = ${{grandTotal}}</strong></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <p></p>
                        <br>
                        <table>
                            <div id="myPaypalButtons" class="a"></div>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- PayPal pop-up, when the "Submit" button gets clicked -->
            
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container *ngIf="products.length ==0">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card">
                    <h1 class="card-title">My Cart</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="center">
                    <img src="./assets/empty_cart-1200x900.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 50%;">
                    <h3>Add item to it now</h3>
                    <button routerLink="/products" class="btn btn-primary">Shop Now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </body>
</html>
```

PayPal Developer Request API (Should show line_items, quantity, item_price)

```
{
    "additional_properties": "xxxxxx",
    "body": {
        "application_context": "xxxxxx",
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": 50
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "header": {
...
```

PayPal Developer Response API (Should show line_items, quantity, item_price)

```
...

"body": {
        "create_time": "2022-03-30T14:02:17Z",
        "id": "5NF87760A7316650M",
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5NF87760A7316650M",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "self"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5NF87760A7316650M",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "approve"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5NF87760A7316650M",
                "method": "PATCH",
                "rel": "update"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5NF87760A7316650M/capture",
                "method": "POST",
                "rel": "capture"
            }
        ],
        "purchase_units": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "50.00"
                },
                "payee": {
                    "email_address": "*****",
                    "merchant_id": "D89E2QT2Q4MYU"
                },
                "reference_id": "default"
            }
        ],
        "status": "CREATED"
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where in your implementation the PayPal order is being created. That's where you need to add the item information, inside `purchase_units`.

You can find an example in the [Checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), bullet #6 in 'Add and modify the code'

```
     {
         "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100",
              "breakdown": {
                "item_total": {  /* Required when including the `items` array */
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100"
                }
              }
            },
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "First Product Name", /* Shows within upper-right dropdown during payment approval */
                "description": "Optional descriptive text..", /* Item details will also be in the completed paypal.com transaction view */
                "unit_amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "50"
                },
                "quantity": "2"
              },
            ]
          }]
      }
```